# Reference request - linear relation of roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I am considering a finite sum that looks something like:

$$\sum_{0 \leq n \leq N} a_n \zeta_{k}^{h(n)}$$

where $h(n)$ and $k$ are integers, not necessarily coprime. Note that $h(n)$ depends on $n$ in a quadratic way. If needed I can write this out explicitly, but it gets a bit messy and for my purposes, it would be better to be able to be able to deal with other cases simultaneously.

My question is then:

$\textbf{For the sum above, describe exactly all possible values of }  a_i \textbf{ such that the sum vanishes}$

I am interested as to whether there are any papers/references that provide the possible values of the set $a_i$ for a given value of $k$ such that this sum vanishes.

Edit: I am equally as interested in the question; given a set $\{a_i\}$, what values of $h(n), k$ can we take such that this sum vanishes?

Comment: For reference, I have seen the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9511209 by Lam/Leung which give possible sizes of the set $\{ a_i \}$, but wasn't able to find a description of the coefficients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the closest I have come so far is Schoenburg's paper here:
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/a-note-on-the-cyclotomic-polynomial/30AB5C650C8F84B00C37E40F05D17A18

which explicitly constructs a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of coefficients $a_i$, but only for a full set of representatives of primitive roots of unity. In my question, we do not generally have a full set of representatives, and they are also do not have to be primitive (though this part should be easy enough to remedy in my situation)

I get the feeling I won't be able to find a result that is any closer to what I'm after at the moment, but will continue my hunt!

Comment: Further: here is a paper by Lenstra which categorises the coefficients completely (relying on Conway/Jones). See theorem 2.2 and 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Every linear dependence between $n^{th}$ roots of unity can be described as follows. The $n^{th}$ roots of unity over $\mathbb{Q}$ generate a field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, the $n^{th}$ cyclotomic field. This field can be written

$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \cong \mathbb{Q}[z]/\Phi_n(z)$$

where $\Phi_n(z)$ is the $n^{th}$ [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), the minimal polynomial of a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity $\zeta_n$. What this means is that every linear dependence between $n^{th}$ roots of unity takes the form $P(\zeta_n) = 0$ where $P(x) = Q(x) \Phi_n(x)$ is a polynomial divisible by $\Phi_n(x)$.

This isn't quite an answer to your question because it's difficult to control the exponents which occur in $P$. But, having fixed the exponents, you can express all $\zeta_n^k$ for $k \ge \deg \Phi_n(x) = \varphi(n)$ in terms of smaller powers of $\zeta_n$ using $\Phi_n(x)$. It will be ugly in general but it will work in small particular cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I actually do know about cyclotomic field extensions etc, I was just ever hopeful that there would be an explicit formula for such coefficients given the work of Mann etc a few decades ago